# How to remove a Python function from a module using C++?

Tags: c++, cpython

Creating an application in C++, I integrated CPython to facilitate the development of certain top-level logics.

The application has a plugin subsystem, which can loaded/unloaded plugins at runtime, this implies to add and remove Python definitions at runtime.

I found that I can add functions with `PyModule_AddFunctions`, and similarly, I can add constants, objects, etc...

But I found no equivalent `PyModule_RemoveFunction`.

**How to remove a Python function from a module using C++?**

Note: Ideally, I would like to avoid solutions like:

- Removing the full module and reloading everything
- Crafting Python code, that when executed would remove the function.

---

Let see an example:

DISCLAIM: I removed most of the error checks for simplicity.

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h> //before std includes

// Just an example function to add/remove from Python
static PyObject* log(PyObject* , PyObject* args)
{
    //Do something 

    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

// Setup a "AppModule" module
PyMODINIT_FUNC initAppModule()
{
    static PyModuleDef AppModuleInfo{
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "AppModule",  // name of module
        nullptr,      // module documentation, may be NULL
        -1,           // size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables.
        nullptr
    };


    const auto AppModule = PyModule_Create(&AppModuleInfo);
    PyModule_AddFunctions(AppModule, AppModuleMethods);

    return AppModule;
}

// Adding a function when a plugin is loaded
void PluginAddingAFunction()
{
    static PyMethodDef AppModuleMethods[]{
        {"log",  log, METH_VARARGS,
         "Log a message in the standard output."},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL} // Sentinel
    };

    PyObject *modName = PyUnicode_FromString("AppModule");
    PyObject *mod = PyImport_Import(modName);

    PyModule_AddFunctions(mod, AppModuleMethods);
}

// Removing the function when the plugin is unloaded
void PluginRemoveAFunction()
{
    PyObject *modName = PyUnicode_FromString("AppModule");
    PyObject *mod = PyImport_Import(modName);

    // How to do this?
    //PyModule_RemoveFunctions(mod, "log");
}


int main(int argn, const char* argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    PyImport_AppendInittab("AppModule", &initAppModule);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *pmodule = PyImport_ImportModule("AppModule");
    
    PluginAddingAFunction(); // <<===== This is done at any time, when loading a plugin

    PyRun_SimpleString("import AppModule\n"
                       "AppModule.log('Hi World')\n"); // <== Example code

    PluginRemoveAFunction(); // <<===== This is done when unloading a plugin

    Py_FinalizeEx();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PyObject_DelAttr` C-apis.

> `int PyObject_DelAttr(PyObject *o, PyObject *attr_name)`
>
> Delete attribute named `attr_name`, for object `o`. Returns `-1` on failure. This is the equivalent of the Python statement `del o.attr_name`
> [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_DelAttr).

So you could do something like this to remove `log` function

```
void PluginRemoveAFunction()
{
    PyObject *modName = PyUnicode_FromString("AppModule");
    PyObject *mod = PyImport_Import(modName);

    PyObject *funcName = PyUnicode_FromString("log");
    PyObject_DelAttr(mod, funcName);
}
```

Comment: Seems a great answer. I am going to test it this evening and then accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: It seems `PyObject_DelAttr` expects an attribute name, not an attribute object. I used `PyUnicode_FromString("log")` and feeded this directly to `PyObject_DelAttr` and it works now.